# Why ArduPi library does not work?

Tags: c++

I tried to use arduPi library and I did what this page says : https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge#step4

but I do not know what is wrong with it ? I tried to run arduPi.cpp file but unfortunately nothing worked

[image]

note : I have Pi 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you made a .o file (`arduPi.o`), not actually the arduPi program. This file is a library that you need to link into the compilation of whatever program you are building with that library. If you are trying to compile the test file `arduPi.cpp`, you would need to do this like so:

```
g++ -lrt -lpthread arduPi.cpp arduPi.o -o arduPi
```

Once that is complete, you can do `sudo ./arduPi`.

I must say, the whole arduPi library and shield setup is marked as "Expert" level on the site you linked - if you do not understand the workings of the c++ compiler and how to link code libraries, it might make sense to read up on that first and get familiar before tackling the arduPi library.

Comment: Thank you sir, but I did exactly as what you did, but when I typed "sudo ./arduPi". I get the message "command not found", I wonder why ?

Comment: According to your screenshot you compiled `arduPi.cpp` without linking in the library, and with `arduPi.o` as the output. That is not correct. You should have first built `arduPi.o` using `wget http://www.cooking-hacks.com/media/cooking/images/documentation/raspberry_arduino_shield/raspberrypi2.zip && unzip raspberrypi2.zip && cd cooking/arduPi && chmod +x install_arduPi && ./install_arduPi && rm install_arduPi && cd ../..` and then used that `arduPi.o` library to compile `arduPi.cpp` as per the `g++`-line above.

Comment: Sir I did what you said I wrote `wget` command and then I wrote `g++` command too but it did not work too. I am sorry but I know nothing about c++ compiler do you have any idea how can I learn it with a few days please ? I really need that

Comment: I forgot to say that the error message was "no such file or directory"

Comment: You need to follow the instructions from your reference webpage one by one, with no mistakes/typos. Easiest is to just copy and execute. If you run into trouble with those - update your original question, show which steps you've done and what output you received, then ask for help. At this point I am not sure from which step your "no such file or directory" comes from.